# How can i pass variable from OnCreate to function(View view)

Tags: android

i have an activity that get a variable from another activity, and i want to display this variable when user click on button.
the problem is SaveFile(View view) method cannot find "SurveyTilte" variable.
How can i pass this variable?

```
public class CreateSurvey extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView Textfile;
    String SurveyTilte;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_survey);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        SurveyTilte = extras.getString("SurveyTilte");
}
}
```

i can't, but the code in OnClickListener because there is an @Override method

```
public void SaveFile(View view) {
Textfile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.surveyDetails);
Textfile.setText(SurveyTilte);
}
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateSurvey.this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateSurvey.this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `String` keyword from `String SurveyTilte = extras.getString("SurveyTilte");` to assign value to the class field and not local variable:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_survey);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        SurveyTilte = extras.getString("SurveyTilte");
}
```

and then

```
public void SaveFile(View view) {
  Textfile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.surveyDetails);
  Textfile.setText(SurveyTilte); // <-- reference field that contains value from intent data
}
```

Comment: yes but it still give my null Text, i mean when "SurveyTilte " get  its value from OnCreate and call it from SaveFile(View view) method its value is null, i removed ```String``` SurveyTilte from OnCreate but it still null

Comment: What value saved in `SurveyTilte` immediately after `onCreate`? Does intent's extra actually contain data?

Comment: yes, when i try ```Textfile.setText(SurveyTilte);``` in onCreate It Working

Comment: Are there any other places you reassign `SurveyTilte`?

Comment: Finally, could you share entire `CreateSurvey` activity code?

Comment: thank you very much it's working 100%, the problem in ```SaveFile(View view)``` was not working, i fixed the method and it is working 100%

Answer (score 0):

This is actually more a matter of java than android.

By doing:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    String SurveyTilte = extras.getString("SurveyTilte");
}
```

What you actually do is creating a local variable separated from your class field variable with the same name, and is 'alive' and available for that specific method scope. Meaning you'll loose its reference (and thus its value) when exiting `onCreate` method.

**What you need to do:**

All you need to do is not to declare a new variable inside `onCreate` but to use the same variable you declared in advanced in your class attributes.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    SurveyTilte = extras.getString("SurveyTilte");
}
```

That's how you can use the same reference for your value in the entire class scope.

Comment: but it give me a null variable when Textfile.setText(SurveyTilte);

Comment: there is no error ,but when "SurveyTilte " get its value from OnCreate and call it from SaveFile(View view) method its value is null, i removed ```String SurveyTilte``` from OnCreate but it still null

Comment: And did you check that in `onCreate` it actually gets a non null value?

Comment: yes, when i try ```Textfile.setText(SurveyTilte);``` in onCreate It Working 100%

Comment: Do you change `SurveyTilte`'s value anywhere else in `CreateSurvey` activity?
Does this `SaveFile` method is in `CreateSurvey` activity?

Comment: thank you very much it's working 100%, the problem in ```SaveFile(View view)``` was not working, i fixed the method and it is working 100%

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you.

```
public class CreateSurvey extends AppCompatActivity {
 TextView Textfile;
 String SurveyTilte;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.create_survey);
     }
  }



public void SaveFile(View view) {
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if(extras != null) {
    SurveyTilte = extras.getString("SurveyTilte");
    Textfile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.surveyDetails);
    Textfile.setText(SurveyTilte);
  } 
}
```